# Initializing tabpage array at declaration

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a windows form with several tabs. I want to have an array of type "TabPage" that will hold every tab and I want to initialize it at declaration. I have already tried

```
TabPage[] tabs = {Tab1, Tab2};
TabPage[] tabs = new TabPage[]{Tab1, Tab2};
TabPage[] tabs = new TabPage[2]{Tab1, Tab2};
```

But none of it works.

In addition I tried iterating through every tab in the tab control to add them somehow to the array, but it seems there is no "ToArray()" method in the "Tab_Control.TabPages" collection and the tabs array doesn't have an "AddRange" method.

How do I initialize the tab pages at array declaration and how do I add them to the array post declaration?

Comment: If that is form level code, you cant initialize them with the `TabPage` references because they wont exist until the ctor runs .  Instead of an array consider a `List<TabPage>` which will be more flexible.

Comment: You might be better off using `List<TabPage>` or even use a `Dictionary<string, TabPage>` or `Dictionary<int, TabPage>` that way you can access your tab pages using an ID. A `List<>` or `Dictionary<>` is scalable so you can always call `.Add()` to add another tab page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems there is no "ToArray()" method in the "Tab_Control.TabPages"
>   collection.

To get an array of tab pages from your tab control, you can use:

```
var pages = tabControl1.TabPages.Cast<TabPage>().ToArray();
```

You also can use `ToList()` method which returns you a `List<TabPage>` which is more flexible than an array.
Also keep in mind you should write this code after `InitializeComponents` or for example in form `Load`.

---

You can not initialize the `tabs` field at form level this way:

```
TabPage[] tabs = new TabPage[] { tabPage1, tabPage2 };
```

You will receive compiler error:

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'tabPage1'

But you can define the array field at form level `TabPage[] tabs` and then in Form Load or in constructor after InitializeComponents, assign values to the array:

```
tabs = new TabPage[] { tabPage1, tabPage2 };
```

Comment: In general, if you want to access those tab pages or use them in a loop, you don't need to keep a reference of them in an array or a list, it's enough to use `tabControl1.TabPages` collection.

Comment: Yes, I just realised that, but still, might as well learn something new. :)

Comment: The `Cast<T>` method is so useful when you want to convert a collection of objects to a list or an array of T objects.

Answer (score 1):

TabPageCollection is already IList and IEnumerable. It is should be just enough.

If you need a simple array syntax you could try this:

```
var tabs = new[] {tabPage1, tabPage2};
```